# What is the added benefit of using 所 in 我所认识的人?

Tags: grammar, word

I found that in Pleco, there is one special usage of 所:

> [noun or pronoun + 所 + verb]
>
> a [with 的 to modify a noun]
>
> - 我所认识的人 // the people I know
> - 大家所提的意见 // the opinions various people put forward

However, I feel that even without the 所, the meaning is the same.

> - 我认识的人
> - 大家提的意见

So what is the added benefits of using 所 in this use case?

Comment: web search using「所」是多余的, 可以去掉？leads to the following https://www.zhihu.com/question/22654460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an advanced question I think.

所 here loans the sense of 所有(的)（owned by）.

The structure 'pronoun + 所 + verb + 的( + noun)' indicates a subject-predicate-object relationship. In my opinion, this could have some **exclusive** effect or a bit emphasis on subject-predicate-object relationship. For example,

> 我所认识的人 // the people I know

我所认识的人 excludes：

- Subject 我， not others like 你，他, and etc.
- Verb 认识， not other verbs like 信任，尊敬, and etc.
- Target 人， not other thing like 东西，事情， and etc.

Compare the two phrases below:

> 1. 我所认识的人
> 2. 我认识的人

1 shows the preciseness of each component, subject, predicate, and object. 2 is just a casual way to say it. That being said, 1 is used when you are trying to be formal, clear or precise, while 2 is used when you don't have to be that formal and precise.

Comment: Thanks. Do you usually use this expression in daily life?

Comment: Yes, whenever I try to be formal or serious, I usually use it. Like 据我所知， 我所认识的人， 大家所提的意见, 我所能给予的（东西）， and etc. It's a common usage of 所.

Answer (score 1):

The word 所 in this context according to the dictionary indicates passive voice. You won't hear `大家所提的意见` by itself, but usually with something along with it:

> 大家所提的意见都被接納。
>
> The ideas you suggested are all accepted.

From the [dictionary](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=.mCn6D&o=e0&sec=sec1&op=v&view=1-1):

> 2. 與「為」或「被」合用，表示被動的意思。
>      如：「他的 作品 為 一般 青年人 所 喜愛。」(His works are loved by young people.)

Personally I feel that using 所 somewhat emphasizes the objects in the sentence, like you really want to point them out.